# How can I move a CheckBox in relation to its image background? (Android)

Tags: android, checkbox

I am setting a background image for a checkBox using the following line of code:

```
 checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

However the checkBox gets automatically positioned to the middle-left of the background image. I want the checkBox to be positioned at the bottom right of the background image. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: which layout do you use?

Comment: It is currently a RelativeLayout. The layout can be changed if needed.

Comment: I originally thought about separating the background image from the checkBox and making it an imageView, then manually putting the checkbox at the bottom right. This would require me to hardcode a link between the CheckBox and the ImageView, which I prefer not to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent layout is Relative, so use this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
checkbox.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And that's it :)

For `LinearLayout`its gonna be:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
checkbox.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**UPDATE**

Actually to align it inside its own space you can do simply `checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM);`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

You may do that only if your `CheckBox` width and height are not `wrap_content`! Another way it will not move anywhere. So you should specify constantly width and height, for example `30dp`, but I'd not recommend you to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why the checkbox won't align itself to the right of the background image when I use Gravity.RIGHT? Gravity.BOTTOM works, but Gravity.RIGHT doesn't.

Comment: I had checked, it worked for me, just make sure width and height are not `wrap_content` and have space in advance where to move, like try to set width `30dp` more for testing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to align your `CheckBox` in the bottom-right on the page

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/myImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="CheckBox"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
    </FrameLayout>
```